# Any way to programmatically build UI elements off the UI thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I know I need to create and add elements to another element on the main UI thread in WPF and you can easily do this when on another thread using the Dispatcher.

However I would like to build my elements off the UI thread then add them all in one batch if possible.

This is because I am building thousands of elements and the couple seconds it takes on the UI thread freezes the whole application.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so; however, you can create a smoother user experience by gradually loading the elements without making the GUI hang completely. This can be done by subscribing to the [`CompositionTarget.Rendering`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx) event, which will be called each time a frame is rendered. If you maintain a list of the view models (and corresponding control types) that you need to add, you can create some (say, fifty) of them and add them the visual tree inside the event handler. The next time the event is invoked, you add fifty more, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible, what you do is you create two UI threads. On one UI thread you build up your window and show some kind of progress indication (progress bar) on the other UI thread. Make your window visible when you've built it up.

http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you to use some composite application patter, like Prims. See [Patterns For Building Composite Applications With WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785479.aspx). 
Prism allows to decouple your apps components, and also load them on demands.
Also you can see: [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707819.aspx)
Hope this helps...